# How to make Android Studio show notifications only for its production releases, not beta releases?

Tags: android-studio

If I remember correctly, Android Studio used to show notifications only for production releases, but it has been showing notifications for beta releases:
[image]

How can I make AS show notifications only for its production releases, not beta releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Android Studio has changed your channel for checking updates. So, visit please: `File -> Settings -> type in search bar "beta" -> change preference`and you will see such image:

[image]

select dropdown options and change update channel which you want, for example stable one:

[image]

I hope it will solve your problem and remove such annoying notifications. I also noticed that smth was changed with my prefs.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I thought I looked into Settings and did not see this.  Not sure whether I looked at the wrong place or AS changed recently.

Comment: Maybe AS changed, but I'm not sure))

Answer (score 1):

to change update channel, open settings;
Appearance & Behavior > Updates